# While loop not working while using bool in C#

Tags: c#, while-loop, boolean

My while loop is not working. There are 3 choices on the menu, and the users keep entering inputs until they press "esc". But the program exits after the user enters one of the choices, and it doesn't return to the menu. How can I fix my while loop? Please help.

```
bool runApp = false;//menu.cs #12 Need to false sinces the loop is true
        Student[] students = new Student[35];
        //Application loop
        while (runApp);
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("\n\tGrade Book Menu\n");
            Console.WriteLine("\t1) Add Student");
            Console.WriteLine("\t2) Enter Student Grades");
            Console.WriteLine("\t3) List Student Grades");
            Console.Write("\nEnter Selection or Press Escape to exit: ");
            ConsoleKeyInfo key = Console.ReadKey();
            if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Escape)
            {
                runApp = false;
            }
            else
            {
                switch (key.Key)
                {
                    case ConsoleKey.NumPad1:
                    case ConsoleKey.D1:
                        //Get the current student count stored in the Student Class variable
                        int indexForNewStudent = Student.GetStudentCount();
                        indexForNewStudent = 0;
                        Console.Write("\nEnter Student Name: ");
                        //Instantiate a Student object and place it in the array of Student objects called student
                        students[indexForNewStudent] = new Student(Console.ReadLine()); //Call overloaded constructor
                        //Increment Student count
                        Student.SetStudentCount(indexForNewStudent + 2); //Add to index to account for new student
                        break;
                    case ConsoleKey.NumPad2:
                    case ConsoleKey.D2:
                        Console.WriteLine("\nEnter the Student Number.  Use List Students to get Student Number.");
                        int studentNumber = 0; //Temporary variable to hold the student number to enter grades
                        //Test the entered string is a number and between 1 and 30
                        if ((int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out studentNumber)) && (studentNumber <= 1) &&
                             (studentNumber >= 30))
                        {
                            //In the event a student has not been added this code will crash
                            if (Student.GetStudentCount() < 0) //Has a student been added?
                                students[studentNumber - 1].EnterStudentScores(); //Subtract 1 from enterd number for array index
                            else
                                Console.WriteLine("A student has not been added");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Invalid Student Number.  Enter a number from 1 to 30");
                        }
                        break;
                    case ConsoleKey.NumPad3:
                    case ConsoleKey.D3:
                        Student.ListStudents(students);
                        break;
                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("Invalid Menu Selection");
                        break;
                }
                Console.Write("Press a key to return to Menu");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
        Console.Write("\nExiting Application.  Press any key to close window... ");
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: This shouldn't work at all. Your boolean flag is set to false before hitting the while loop...

Comment: do you know how the **while** loop works ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize runApp to true and fix this line by removing the semicolon ";"

```
while (runApp);
```

Should be

```
while (runApp)
```

Answer (score 3):

You have two problems:

1. The "runApp" variable needs to initialize to true. This allows the loop to run until the "escape" key sets it to false.
2. Remove the semicolon after `while(runApp)`. This causes the loop to just spin until the condition is false (which is probably why the variable was set to false in the first place). Removing it allows the code in {} to be executed until the condition goes to false (which happens on the escape key press.

Let me know if I can clarify any of that!

Answer (score 0):

Change to runApp to true:

```
bool runApp = true;
```

Comment: This misses the semicolon after the while loop

Comment: that's not enough. He's got also a semicolon right after the while statement.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the first lines:

```
bool runApp = true; //this condition needs to be true or it won't enter
        Student[] students = new Student[35];
        //Application loop
        while (runApp) //you need no ";" or it won't execute the loop
```

1. The runApp has to be true;
2. You need to remove the semicolon or it won't loop the code in the brackets.